# How to configure queue_classic logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, task-queue, worker-process

I couldn't find anywhere a solution on how to make queue_classic write logs to a file. Scrolls, which Queue_Classic uses for logging, doesn't seem to have any example either.

Could someone provide a working example?

Comment: you can also ask your question to Queue_Classic gem autors on github if can't find answer in google.

Answer (score 0):

The logging within the method called by QC will be the source for the logging. For example, in rails. Any call to Rails.logger will go to the log file appropriate to your RAILS_ENV. The log data coming from scrolls goes to stdout, so you could pipe STDOUT from your queues to a log file when you start them.

You could control your queues with god.rb giving a god.rb configuration instance similar to this (I've left your configuration for number of queues, directories, etc up to you):

```
number_queues.times do |queue_num|
  God.watch do |w|
    w.name = "QC-#{queue_num}"
    w.group = "QC"
    w.interval = 5.minutes
    w.start = "bundle exec rake queue:work" # This is your rake task to start QC listening
    w.gid = 'nginx' 
    w.uid = 'nginx'
    w.dir = rails_root
    w.keepalive
    w.env = {"RAILS_ENV" => rails_env} 
    w.log = "#{log_dir}/qc.stdout.log"  # Or....    "#{log_dir}//qc-#{queue_num}.stdout.log"

    # determine the state on startup
    w.transition(:init, { true => :up, false => :start }) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

FWIW, I find the STDOUT log data to be less than helpful and may end up just sending it to the bitbucket.

If the log data is useless, we should consider removing it.

DEBUG is very nice when I'm running it from a commandline. For times when I am trying to figure out what I've done to bork everything up (usually bundling issues, path issues, etc). Or times when I am going to demo what is going on in a queue.

For me, INFO logging consists of the standard lib=queue_classic level=info action=insert_job elapsed=16 message and any STDOUT/STDERR from forked executions or from PostgreSQL. I've not extended any of the logging classes since scrolls goes to STDOUT and my tasks are in an environment that provides logging.

Sure, it could be removed. I think that REALLY depends on the environment and what the queue is doing. If I were to be doing something that did not have Rails.logger then I would use the QC.log and scrolls more effectively and instrument my tasks in that manner.

As I play with it, I may keep my configuration as-is just because of the output coming from methods/applications called by the tasks themselves. I might decide to override QC.log code to add date/time. I am still working to determine what fits my needs.

Sorry, my last line was really focused on the environment example I had given.

original here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/queue_classic/issues/101)